# When script runs it adds 4px to the height of my container every second, only happens in firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

When you press "start" on my website it activates the stop watch script I have. It works fine on all browsers except firefox. In firefox every second that ticks over it adds usally 4px's or more to the height of the container.. So strange.. Any ideas on how to fix? I am using Firefox 34 on Windows 7.

**[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJjEGV)**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Runna - Track your run!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <header>
        <img src="imgs/logo-blue.png" />
    </header>
    <div id="map-container">
       <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d11564.804405086046!2d172.59430635!3d-43.56069255!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2snz!4v1418977732755" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="show-controls"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></div>
    <section id="control-container">
        <div class="column left">

                 <div id="left-wrapper">
                    <div class="left-top">
                       <ul>
                          <li><b>Distance</b></li>
                          <li>17.7KM</li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="left-bottom">
                        <ul>
                          <li><b>Duration</b></li>
                          <li><span id="stop-watch"><time>00:00:00</time></span></li>
                       </ul>
                    </div>
                 </div>

        </div>
        <div class="column middle">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" class="arrow"><div><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div></a>
                      <a href="#" id="start"><div>START</div></a>
                      <a href="#" id="clear"><div>STOP</div></a>
                      <a href="#" id="stop"><div>PAUSE</div></a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="column right"></div>
    </section>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arrowButton = $('a.arrow');
    var controlContainer = $('#control-container');



    arrowButton.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        controlContainer.fadeOut('fast');
        $('.show-controls').show();
        $('#map-container').css('height', '87vh');
    });

    $('.show-controls').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        controlContainer.fadeIn('fast');
        $('.show-controls').hide();
        $('#map-container').css('height', '65vh');
    });

// Stop watch script

var h2 = document.getElementById('stop-watch'),
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    h2.innerHTML = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}

/* Start button */
start.onclick = function(){
    timer();
}

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h2.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}




});
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 100% arial;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */ 
}

#wrapper {
   height: 100vh;
}

.show-controls {
   width: 100%;
   height: 8vh;
   background: black;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   position: relative;
   display: none; /*Initially hidden, will use jQuery to reveal when needed*/
}

.fa-chevron-up {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#map-container {
   height: 65vh;
}

.show-controls:hover {
   background: green;
}
.column.middle ul, .column.middle nav, .column.middle li {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.column.middle nav {
  display: inline-block;
}

.column.middle li {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.column.middle li a {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.column.middle li a div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

    header {
     width: 100%;
     height: 5vh;
     background: black;
     position: relative;


    }
    header img {
      height: 80%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    #control-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30vh;
        background: black;
        display: table;
    }
    .column {
        display: table-cell;
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .row {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .left {
        background: #0f0f0f;
        width: 33.3%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .middle {
        background: black;
        width: 33.3%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .right {
        background: #0f0f0f;
        width: 33.3%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    nav ul {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav li {
        display: block;
    }
    nav a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 30px;
    }
    nav a:hover {
        background: green;
    }

#left-wrapper {
   height: 100%;
}

.left-top, .left-bottom {
   height: 50%;
   position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.left-top ul, .left-bottom ul {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: The "vh" inuts seem to cause this behavior. When I change the controls units, they seems to stop the increment.

Comment: You are right. I have a feeling this is a bug in firefox? What do you think?

Comment: It caught my eye because I'd never seen them before. So don't now what is expected behavior. Could be a bug, could be a unfortunate convergence of rules.

Comment: Hmm yeah, it works on every other browser fine though even IE. I will file a bug on bugzilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have seem to have fixed this issue by removing `overflow: hidden` from the `*` selector at the top of my css and I have added it to the `html` selector that I have now created.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 100% arial;
    overflow: hidden; /*<-- Removed from here*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
     box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */ 
}

html {
  overflow: hidden; /*<-- Added here*/
}
```